# How to disable Clojure assertions, including preconditions?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

What are some good ways to disable Clojure assertions (including preconditions and postconditions) in the REPL? For an arbitrary Leiningen profile?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Per https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/b82b228/sample.project.clj#L291

Set `:global-vars` to `{*assert* false}` in your `profiles.clj`.

You can put the above setting in whatever Leiningen profiles you want.

Comment: Line 276 as of today.