# Assertions in Clojure applications enabled by default when running uberjar built with leiningen

Tags: clojure

Should assertions be enabled by default when running a Clojure application as a jar?

We use leiningen to build an uberjar and then `java -jar ...` to run it and I've just found out that `*assert*` is true.

I couldn't find what default value should this dynamic variable hold but I thought it would be false (and only set to true in REPL development environment).

This lead to a nasty issue in combination with `future` where a precondition assertion error caused the future thread to die and we didn't know what happened (because we caught only `Exception` not `Throwable`).

I went through the source code of [`clojure.lang.RT`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/RT.java#L199) but I couldn't figure out where is the `*assert*` var set to true.

I've also found the option `:global-vars` in the [leinigen sample project](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/7357010431c926abb559d55b295fe1ba7791ed20/sample.project.clj#L286) (this is mentioned in [How to disable Clojure assertions, including preconditions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24949418/how-to-disable-clojure-assertions-including-preconditions)).
That looks reasonable but I thought that for "production" build I would get `*assert* false` automatically.

**EDIT**: I missed that little `T` thing (boolean true) used to initialize `*assert*` variable in `RT.java`. However, still curious why that's the default and what is the recommended way to turn off assertions (if it's even recommended).

Comment: Ok, I missed that little `T` thing (boolean true) used to initialize `*assert*` variable in `RT.java`. However, still curious why that's the default and what is the recommended way to turn off assertions (if it's even recommended).

Answer (score 6):

From the source, `clojure.core/assert` is a macro that evaluates `*assert*` at compile time:

```
(defmacro assert
  "Evaluates expr and throws an exception if it does not evaluate to
  logical true."
  {:added "1.0"}
  ([x]
     (when *assert*
       `(when-not ~x
          (throw (new AssertionError (str "Assert failed: " (pr-str '~x)))))))
  ([x message]
     (when *assert*
       `(when-not ~x
          (throw (new AssertionError (str "Assert failed: " ~message "\n" (pr-str '~x))))))))
```

This means that both `alter-var-root` and `binding` cannot change the behavior of `assert`, since they operate at runtime, after `assert` has already evaluated `*assert*`.  Therefore, the `:global-vars` option in `project.clj`:

```
  :global-vars {*warn-on-reflection* false
                *assert* false }
```

is the only solution that will work, since it is evaluated before macro expansion. With this test code:

```
(dotest
  (spyxx *assert*)
  (assert false "Don't do that!")
  (println "past the assertion"))
```

we get result:

```
----------------------------------
   Clojure 1.9.0    Java 10.0.1
----------------------------------

lein test tst.demo.core
*assert* => <#java.lang.Boolean false>
past the assertion

Ran 2 tests containing 0 assertions.
0 failures, 0 errors.
lein test  32.28s user 0.56s system 349% cpu 9.387 total
```